# Object Value Passing in C++ functions

Tags: c++, xcode, oop

```
    #include <string>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <fstream>
    using namespace std;

class cal
{
    int x, y;
public:
    void set(int a, int b)
    {
        x = a;
        y = b;
    }
    cal add(cal c1, cal c2)
    {
        cal temp;
        temp.x = c1.x + c2.x;
        temp.y = c1.y + c2.y;
        return temp;
    }
    void display()
    {
        cout << x << y; //display output
    }

};
int main()
{
    cal c1, c2, c3, c4;
    c1.set(10, 30);
    c2.set(20, 40);
    c4 = c3.add(c1, c2);
    c4.display();
}
```

I have tried this code in Xcode. but its not working. I'm not getting any error either.

I'm getting `"c4.display Thread1:breakpoint 1.1"`

Can please anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

What I'm doing is adding two objects `First` and `Second` value together and `Display`.

And Also I checked info at c4.display()
and im getting this

> Printing description of c4: (cal) c4 = (x = 30, y = 70) (lldb)

Comment: How can this code compile without an include of <iostream>?  And please format the code a little better.

Comment: it was in the code. but i didnt add them here. because i thought its not very important.@PaulMcKenzie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add `#include <iostream>` to the top it will compile and run just fine.

Comment: it was in the code. but i didnt put it here. updated the code.

Comment: Try opening a new test project and pasting your code in there to see if it works because it works just fine for me.

Comment: oops. you are right. its worked..